# Typo3 v7.6 extbase render tt_content with pi-extension in it

Tags: plugins, typo3, extbase

I have a problem. This code works when loading a tt_content element in my Controller from my Extenstion.

```
$cObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();

$ttContentConfig = array(
    'tables'       => 'tt_content',
    'source'       => 123,
    'dontCheckPid' => 1
);

var_dump( $cObj->RECORDS($ttContentConfig) );
```

But my problem is when I use a specific tt_content uid where an another plugin (foreign one, not from my extension) is connected in it then it don't output anything at all.
It's just giving me a string(50) with nothing in it, which is strange actually cause it should show something when there are 50 chars available :-(

But when I am using fluid  then I'll get this INT_SCRIPT marker:
<!--INT_SCRIPT.061e018a9a1771fb1f9d0f4a0b71926b-->

Do I have to render this INT_SCRIPT in some way?
Or is there an another way to render the output so that the plugin in that tt_content element gets also rendered or something like this?

Thanks for helping me out and have a great day.

Comment: Really strange behaviour here.
I did it with this:
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fluidLoadRecord"> 123</f:cObject>

Working so far. But when page is reIoading and cache is working than I'll not get the output again. It's gone until I clear the cache.

I tried it with other extensions which are in an tt_content element. Even tt_news LIST is doing it right with active cache.

Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: No one knows how to?